# How to verify checkboxes on maximum 2 in a row

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

How to verify the checkbox on a section, maximum 10, 2 in a row, and the checkbox is checked?

**To verify checkbox is checked**

```
Boolean isCheckboxChecked = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'checkboxSection')]//input[@type='checkbox']")).isSelected();
```

**To verify max checkbox on that section is 10**

```
Boolean isCheckboxMaxTen = 
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'checkboxSection')]//input[@type='checkbox']")).size() <= 10;
```

**To verify max 2 checkbox in a row**

Any idea how to verify `max 2 checkbox in a row`

```
if ((isCheckboxChecked == true) && (isCheckboxMaxTen == true) && (isCheckboxTwoInARow == true)){
    // Pass
}
else
{
    // Fail
}
```

Added html code

```
<form name="formApp" method="post" action="/apps/GeneralManager">
    <div class="USK_A">
    <img class="BOL_B" alt="" src="http://apps.com"/>
        <div class="MOV_HOL_A">
            <p class="bold">
                <ul class="form_movie">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="3000000190795" name="point_id"/>
                        Movie_A
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <p class="mv5">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please provide some HTML so that we can lookup...

Comment: @Vivek Singh, added html code, thanks